# How to change the value in data.table with chaining?

Tags: r, data.table

Consider the below statements :

```
library(data.table)
irD <- data.table(iris)

irD[Species == "setosa", ][Petal.Width >= 0.3, 
  Sepal.Length1 := Sepal.Length + 1]
irD
```

If you will check the output, there is no column name Sepal.Length1 in the data.table irD.

However, if I dont use chaining, I am able to get the new column.

```
irD[Species == "setosa" & Petal.Width >= 0.3, 
  Sepal.Length1 := Sepal.Length + 1]
irD
```

My question is whether, it is possible to change values in a `data.table` with chaining? To me, chaining helps in writing more cleaner code, and that's why I want to use chaining.

Comment: It is because you are assigning (`:=`) to a subset of dataset

Comment: Is there any solution, where I can do subsetting, using chaining, yet able to change the values in the original dataset?

Comment: when you do subsetting in chain it is no longer the original dataset but its subset